# Method to return values after predicate is satisfied

Tags: scala

To match everything up to a condition I use :

```
val c = "this is a test".split(" ").toList//> c  : List[String] = List(this, is, a, test)

c.takeWhile({x => !x.equals("is")})       //> res0: List[String] = List(this)
```

Is there a method that is similar to `takeWhile` except it takes everything after the predicate is satisifed ?
 So something like `c.takeAfter({x => x.equals("is")})` returns `List("a" , "test");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dropWhile`:

```
scala>   c.dropWhile(_ != "is")
res4: List[String] = List(is, a, test)
```

This will drop all the elements until it hits the predicate, note that the predicated string is included so you need to check if the list is empty and if not take the tail.

Comment: I'd argue that you should use: `c.dropWhile(_ != "is").drop(1)`. Note that `tail` is a partial function, i.e. will throw on an empty list:

`List[String]("adsfasdf").dropWhile(_ != "is").tail` results in a thrown exception: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`. Not so with `drop`: `scala> List[String]("asdfasdf").dropWhile(_ != "is").drop(1)
res16: List[String] = List()`

Comment: Agreed, I also wrote that before calling `tail` one has to check if the list is empty, but `drop(1)` (which I didn't think about) is surely a more suited option.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `span` which bisects the list into those items that hold a predicate up to the first invalidated, for instance

```
val (l,r) = c.span( _ != "is" )
```

which delivers

```
l: List(this)
r: List(is, a, test)
```